# What is happening in this make clean?

Tags: makefile

I am learning more about makefiles and came across an example I don't quite understand. What is happening in make clean? It is forcibly removing all object files in /obj, but I am lost after that. I know it also removes the exe file, but how is that translated in the code?

```
IDIR =../include
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-I$(IDIR)

ODIR=obj
LDIR =../lib

LIBS=-lm

_DEPS = hellomake.h
DEPS = $(patsubst %,$(IDIR)/%,$(_DEPS))

_OBJ = hellomake.o hellofunc.o
OBJ = $(patsubst %,$(ODIR)/%,$(_OBJ))


$(ODIR)/%.o: %.c $(DEPS)
        $(CC) -c -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS)

../hellomake: $(OBJ)
        gcc -o $@ $^ $(CFLAGS) $(LIBS)

.PHONY: clean

clean:
        rm -f $(ODIR)/*.o *~ core $(INCDIR)/*~
```

Comment: Doesn't look like it removes `hellomake`.

Comment: `$(INCDIR)` looks like it's supposed to be `$(IDIR)` because `INCDIR` isn't defined anywhere.

Comment: what is going on in `*~ core $(INCDIR)/*~` if it doesn't remove hellomake?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's look at the line

```
rm -f $(ODIR)/*.o *~ core $(INCDIR)/*~
```

The first thing `make` does is expanding the `$(...)` variables, leading to:

```
rm -f obj/*.o *~ core /*~
```

The last part is likely a bug: `INCDIR` is not defined, so it expands to nothing. Did you mean `$(IDIR)` instead?

The second thing `make` does is running the resulting line via `/bin/sh -c ...`. The shell expands things like wildcards.

Let's assume the object files in `obj` are `hellomake.o` and `hellofunc.o`. Then `obj/*.o` becomes `obj/hellofunc.o obj/hellomake.o`.

`*~` matches all files in the current directory that end with `~`. Why would you have such a file? Because when you use emacs to edit a file `foo`, it will leave a [backup copy under `foo~`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Backup-Names.html) by default. So this is intended to remove emacs backup files.

`core` is what you normally get when you enable [core dumps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Core_dump) and a program you run crashes (and you're not using systemd). It can be used to debug the crash.

The last pattern looks like it was meant to match emacs backup files in `INCDIR`, but because that's unset, it tries to find backup files in the root directory, `/`. Normally there are no files at all in `/`, let alone emacs backups.

If a pattern matches no files, the default behavior of the shell is to leave it unexpanded. So the last part (`/*~`) is likely left as-is. Let's assume you have no backup files in the current directory either, so `*~` is also left alone:

```
rm -f obj/hellofunc.o obj/hellomake.o *~ core /*~
```

This line runs `rm`, passing it an array of strings as arguments:

```
{ "rm", "-f", "obj/hellofunc.o", "obj/hellomake.o", "*~", "core", "/*~" }
```

`rm` (following convention) scans its arguments for strings beginning with `-`, which it processes as options. In this case there's one option, `f`. `f` ("force") tells `rm` to not ask about files you don't have write permissions for; just delete them anyway. It also suppresses errors such as those you'd normally get for trying to delete non-existent files. (In particular, you probably don't have a file literally called `*~`.)

So the whole thing deletes

- object files in `obj/`
- `core` in the current directory
- emacs backup files in the current directory
- emacs backup files in `/` (which probably don't exist, and if they exist, you probably don't have permissions to delete)

while ignoring any errors.